# Java: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4?

Tags: java, loops

I understand the reason behind this exception and I checked my code multiple times. However, I think my index is within the index bound. Can anyone help me out here? Just a side note: assume the condition for while loop will be satisfied. That is, num is at most 3.

```
 int suit;
 int num = 0;
 String[] suitList = {"c", "d", "h", "s"};
 for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    while (suitList[num].equals(testHand[i].substring(0,1)) == false){
        num++;
    }            
    suit = num + 1;
 }
```

Comment: @Eran I think you are right!

Answer (score 1):

You should reset num to 0 for each iteration of the for loop:

```
int suit;
String[] suitList = {"c", "d", "h", "s"};
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
   int num = 0;
   while (suitList[num].equals(testHand[i].substring(0,1)) == false){
       num++;
   }            
   suit = num + 1;
}
```

Otherwise, it may exceed `3` after the first iteration of the for loop.

BTW, your condition can be improved as follows:

```
int suit;
String[] suitList = {"c", "d", "h", "s"};
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
   int num = 0;
   while (!testHand[i].startsWith(suitList[num]))) {
       num++;
   }            
   suit = num + 1;
}
```

Comment: I think the code can be a little cleaner if we will not use "assumptions" on the size of the testHand array.
What about:
`for (int i = 0; i < testHand.length; i++)` or even `for (String hand: testHand)`